# Simplificar la declaración de variables con un nombre común

Tags: javascript

Tengo variables con nombre común, y se diferencian por el número que tienen asignado, es decir:

```
let nombre1 = ;
let nombre2 = ;
let nombre3 = ;
...
let nombre500 = ;
```

¿Existe alguna forma más compacta de declararlas?

Comment: Declara un [arreglo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias @HeytalePazguato

Con ello entonces lo puedo crear de esta forma:

```
let nombre=[];
...
myfunction() {
nombre[0]="valor";
nombre[1]=$("#id").val();
console.log(nombre[1]);
}
```

Así ya no declaro una por una y les voy asignando un valor conforme las vaya utilizando